# replace with fade effect

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I want to replace an `.image` with some text, I can do that with following code:

```
$(this).parents().find(".image").replaceWith('some text');
```

But how can I remove the `.image` with the the `fadeOut` effect and then replace it?

I have tried following but it doesn't work.

```
$(this).parents().find(".image").fadeOut().replaceWith('some text');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a `callback` function to some jQuery functions to call that function when it has done doing things defined in itself. Go ahead and search if `.fadeOut` method accepts `callback` function. If it does, then replace your image with text in that function. Actually, it does.

```
$(this).parents().find(".image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('some text');
});
```

Comment: *Note*: this works because the code in `fadeOut(1000, function() { ... });` will execute only after the `fadeOut` is done.